# SQL - Combination of Distinct & Count in a table

Tags: sql

Need a simple query to summarize result from a table where 3 columns are present:
Order ID, Category & Brand.

The summary should contain order ID, distinct count of category and distinct count of brand belonging to the order ID.

**Sample Data:**

```
orderno product brand
1       A       Z
1       A       X
1       B       Y
2       C       X
2       B       X
3       C       X
3       B       Y
```

**Expected Result:**

```
orderno product brand
1       2       3
2       2       1
3       2       2
```

[Sample Data & Summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vluzu.png)

Comment: I removed the extraneous database tags.  And, I'll give you a hint:  `count(distinct )`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [ask] before posting questions. Among the others, you should post the code you tried and the problems you're having; also, please post data as formatted text, not images

Answer (score 0):

Use `DISTINCT` of `COUNT` to get your expected result:

```
select orderno, count(distinct product) as product, count(distinct brand) as brand
from testtable
group by orderno
```

Sample execution with the given data

```
declare @test1 table (orderno int, product varchar(2), brand varchar(2))
insert into @test1 (orderno, product, brand) values 
(1, 'A', 'Z'),
(1, 'A', 'X'),
(1, 'B', 'Y'),
(2, 'C', 'X'),
(2, 'B', 'X'),
(3, 'C', 'X'),
(3, 'B', 'Y');

select orderno, count(distinct product) as product, count(distinct brand) as brand
from @test1
group by orderno
```

Result:

```
orderno product brand
1       2       3
2       2       1
3       2       2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,.

```
 select orderno,count(DISTINCT product) product,COUNT(DISTINCT brand) brand       
 from data
 GROUP by orderno
```

The output.,

```
orderno     product     brand
----------- ----------- -----------
1           2           3
2           2           1
3           2           2
```